# how to call onActivityResult in cordova ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, upi

Any wrapper class available for onActivityResult in cordova/Ionic app.
Needs for UPI deep linking response.
Is any UPI common library available  for ionic/cordova app.
Following http://www.npci.org.in/documents/UPI-Linking-Specs-ver-1.1_draft.pdf

Comment: So what is your exect question? Do want to know how to use `onActivityResult()` in a cordova plugin or do you search a ready to use plugin?

Comment: want to know how to use onActivityResult() in cordova plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onActivityResult()` in a cordova plugin like this:

E.g. in your `execute` method:

```
cordova.setActivityResultCallback(this);
cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent);
```

And the corresponding method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(...) {
    super.onActivityResult(...);
}
```

Comment: I used this method but not getting response from intent  where i want to display response on ui view using callbackContext